# Not able to get Multiple text fields values in Controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to get multiple text field values in the controller using below code but I do not see all the values in the controller, please help me out

**JSP: **

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Sl.No</td>
        <td>Subjects</td>
        <td>Max. Questions</td> 
        <td>Max. Marks</td>
        <td>Qualify Marks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="subject in subjectss">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox'  value={{subject.sid}} data-ng-checked="{{subject.status == 1 ? true : false}}"> {{subject.subjectName}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.max_questions"  class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.max_marks" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.qual_marks" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
```

**Controller.js (onSubmit)**

```
app.controller('ModelExamController',['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$location', 'appURL', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $http, $location, appURL) {
$scope.updateModelExam = function(){
     angular.forEach($scope.subjectss, function(subject){
        alert("111: "+$scope.subject.max_questions[$scope.i]);
        $scope.i=$scope.i+1;
    });
}
}
```

[Designed Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMwZa.png)

Comment: You are using `$scope.subject.max_questions` instead you should be using `subject.max_questions` in your forEach.

Comment: @Amit By using `subject.max_questions` i am getting the list values, i dont want list values. i want values which are entered in text fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the solution:**

```
$scope.updateModelExam = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.subjectss, function(subject){
        alert("q_marks: "+subject.qual_marks);
        alert("m_marks: "+subject.qual_marks);
        alert("m_ques: "+subject.max_questions);
    });
}
```

Comment: `$scope.subjectss = []; $scope.subjectss.push(sub)`

Comment: Yeah ,I only assign empty object because you not given subjectss array value.otherwise impossible for me to check code is correct or wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :
HTML::

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Sl.No</td>
    <td>Subjects</td>
    <td>Max. Questions</td>
    <td>Max. Marks</td>
    <td>Qualify Marks</td>
</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="subject in subjectss">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox'  value={{subject.sid}} data-ng-checked="{{subject.status == 1 ? true : false}}"> {{subject.subjectName}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.max_questions"  class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.max_marks" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subject.qual_marks" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateModelExam()" >Update</button>
```

Controller:

```
var sub = {
 max_questions:'',
  max_marks: '',
   qual_marks: '',
    subjectName:'',
    status: 1,
   sid: ''
 }
 $scope.subjectss = [];
  $scope.subjectss.push(sub)
  $scope.updateModelExam = function(){
   angular.forEach($scope.subjectss, function(subject){
    console.log("111: ",subject.max_questions);
    $scope.i=$scope.i+1;
  });
}
```

let me know if you are facing any problem,

Comment: By this i am getting the list values, i dont want list values. i want values which are entered in text fields

Comment: Not working. After using above code table is getting reset, showing zero rows

Comment: @SantoshDJ push object with empty field.I modified my code.Plz check once